# deprecated messages in klein routes manager with php 8.1

Tags: php, routes

Is there some fork of the klein route manager that works fine eith php 8.1, actually i get a lot of "deprecated" warnings
If there is no, Is there some similare or better route manager to my own project ?

I want a way to ensure that my php projects using the klein laravel dont get deprecated in php 8.1

Answer (score 1):

start using something more suitable (unfortunately klein.php no longer supported, don't pull skeletons from the wardrobe =))
If you already use Laravel, use [it's router](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing), it will simplify your development in the long-term support